# Is this the proper/right way of coding?

Tags: android, oncreate, edittextpreference

I have these codes below the Oncreate.

Could someone tell me if this is the right way of coding?

If not the proper way, would you please give me some suggestions?

Thanks alot.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(main_activity.SHARED_PREFS_NAME);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.wallpaper_settings);

    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

Preference button1 = (Preference)findPreference("button1");
button1.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) { 
                //for login   
                return true;
            }
        });


Preference button2 = (Preference)findPreference("button2");
button2.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) { 
                //for new password 
                return true;
            }
        });


Preference button3 = (Preference)findPreference("button3");
button3.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) { 
                //for reset password
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Edit: fixed errors

Comment: it is working, but I got frames being skipping after I updated the Eclipse and after I put these codes in.  So I am not sure what is going.... MY app crashes sometimes too.

Comment: what crash log u get? Is it PreferenceActivity?

Comment: it was saying something like The application may be doing too much work on its main thread…Skipped 64 frames.  Sometimes no frame skipping, sometimes 74 frames skipped, etc.

Comment: Can someone please help?